# Android Auto unusable

Tags: performance, resource-monitoring, google-pixel-2, android-auto

I have a Google Pixel 2 XL and a Sony XAV-AX100.

More often than not, when I connect the phone to the car, Android Auto is unusable. Everything is sooooo slow, that I have to reboot the phone. I can struggle to get Google Maps to work and if it does, it's often lagging behind so directions aren't accurate.

Playing music through Google Play Music will work, eventually, but every few minutes, it will stop momentarily and then continue (much like a CD skipping). This happens to other audio apps such as Pocket Casts too.

Once the phone has been rebooted, it works perfectly.

I've removed all the apps I don't really need, as well as some that I found reported as bad for this online.

Is there a way I can find out what is hogging the resources of my phone when I try to use Android Auto? I think the phone doesn't run as well at times of normal usage, but nothing like what I see in Android Auto.

I have issues with the Sony XAV-AX100, which Sony are now refusing to resolve because my warranty expired, even though I reported these before it did!

Comment: Google Pixel 2 XL is certainly powerful enough to handle Android Auto even without removal of unnecessary / unused applications, so this seems to be more like related to Android Auto itself or its implementation in your car. I've heard that car manufacturers didn't make their homework well and implementation of car's endpoint of Android Auto is often very poor. Do you have, by any chance, an ability to test these two phones in some other Android Auto-enabled car?

Comment: I don't have access to another Android Auto enabled car. Although, since I wrote this question, I had numerous other issues with the head unit and got it replaced for a newer one. I don't have anywhere near the same amount of issues I had with the old one, but I do occasionally have performance issues. Nothing like what it was though!